# Recursive way to count distinct number of elements in array

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Let's assume I have this array: ARR = {5, 7, 3, 3, 7, 5}
and I also have the size ( = 6 in this example ) so the recursive function should return 3.

this is the declaration of the function/method:

```
int f(arr, size);
```

I tried this thing:

```
count = 0;
if(size == 1)
   return 1;
if(x[i] != f(arr, size-1)
    count++;

return count;
```

but it doesn't work, as f(arr, size-1) doesn't walk through all the elements of the array and compare.

hopefully you guys could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
private static int f(int[] arr, int size) {
    if (size <= 1) return 0; // there can't be duplicates if there are not even 2 elements!
    return f(arr, size - 1) + (inArray(arr, size - 1, arr[size - 1]) ? 1 : 0);
}

private static boolean inArray(int[] arr, int size, int elem) {
    if (size == 0) return false;
    return arr[size - 1] == elem || inArray(arr, size - 1, elem);
}
```

Basically the logic is this:

- The `size` indicates the first N elements in `arr` that we actually care about.
- If `size` is less than 2, we know there can't be any duplicates, so return 0.
- Now for the recursion case, we return either 1 or 0 depending on whether the last element is in the rest of the array, plus whatever number of duplicates in the rest of the array ("the last element" means `array[size - 1]` and "the rest" means calling the function with `size - 1`.)
- To determine whether an element is in an array, I used a recursive method as well, with a similar idea (check if the last element is `elem`, then check if the rest contains `elem`).